# UPDATE statement using two arrays at the same index in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a table, `entities` with a column, `contacts` that is an array of ids from another table, `contacts`. The contacts table has the columns `first_name` and `last_name`, and I have an array of first names, `firstNames` and last names, `lastNames` to pass in.

How would you update the `contacts` column in the `entities` table with one query that properly gets all of the contacts with first name `firstNames[0]` AND last name `lastNames[0]`, and all of the contacts with first name `firstNames[1]` AND last name `lastNames[1]`, and [...] all of the contacts with first name `firstNames[n]` AND last name `lastNames[n]`?

My initial thought was something like `UPDATE entities SET contacts = (SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ANY(firstNames) AND last_name = ANY(lastNames)`.

The problem with this arrises when the `contacts` table is like this:

```
first_name | last_name
----------------------
Bob        | Jones
Bob        | Miller
David      | Miller
```

If I wanted to set the `contacts` column to the Ids for Bob Jones and David Miller, but NOT Bob Miller, and I passed in `['Bob', 'David']` for `firstNames` and `['Jones', 'Miller']` for `lastNames` in the above query, Bob Miller would also get added to the `contacts` column.

Answer (score 0):

May be you look for something like this:

```
WITH x AS (
       SELECT 'Bob'::text AS firstName, 'Jones'::text AS lastName
 UNION SELECT 'David', 'Miller'
 UNION SELECT 'Bob', 'Miller'
)
SELECT *
  FROM x
 WHERE (firstName, lastName) = ANY (ARRAY [
              ('Bob'::text, 'Jones'::text),
              ('David'::text, 'Miller'::text)
       ]);
```

Yet another way:

```
WITH x AS (
       SELECT 'Bob'::text AS firstName, 'Jones'::text AS lastName
 UNION SELECT 'David', 'Miller'
 UNION SELECT 'Bob', 'Miller'
)
SELECT *
  FROM x
 WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
         FROM (SELECT ARRAY [
                  ['Bob', 'Jones'],
                  ['David', 'Miller']]::text[][] AS n
              ) AS n
         JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, array_upper(n, 1)) AS i ON true 
        WHERE firstName = n[i][1]
          AND lastName = n[i][2]
 );
```